# Python regex error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 35

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this regex pattern:
`(?P<prefix>.*)(?<!\\)\((?P<words>.+)(?<!\\)\)(?P<postfix>.*)`

This regex is supposed to match a string like this:
`hello my (friend|enemy) nice to see you again`

The `prefix` group should capture `hello my`.
The `words` group should capture `friend|enemy`.
The `postfix` group should capture `nice to see you again`

This regex also uses lookbehinds to check if `(` and `)` are escaped using `\` in string. For example, these two samples should **not** be detected since there is a `\` before `(` and `)`:
`hello my \(friend|enemy) nice to see you again`
`hello my (friend|enemy\) nice to see you again`

This pattern works well when I check it using online websites but when I try to run in in python (I'm using python 3.7), it throws the following error:
`re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 35`

What is the problem?

Edit:
Here is how I use it in python:

```py
pattern = "(?P<prefix>.*)(?<!\\)\((?P<words>.+)(?<!\\)\)(?P<postfix>.*)"
match = re.search(pattern, line)
```

Comment: Please post the part of your code that defines and uses the regex

Comment: You need to use a raw string (`r"..."`), to avoid issues with escaping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Md Narimani
as @erhumoro suggested in comments, instead of:

```
line = "hello my (friend|enemy) nice to see you again"
pattern = "(?P<prefix>.*)(?<!\\)\((?P<words>.+)(?<!\\)\)(?P<postfix>.*)"
match = re.search(pattern, line)
```

Do:

```
line = "hello my (friend|enemy) nice to see you again"
pattern = r"(?P<prefix>.*)(?<!\\)\((?P<words>.+)(?<!\\)\)(?P<postfix>.*)"
match = re.search(pattern, line)
```

It is because of problems with escaping characters.

Comment: Thanks. Since I read the `line` from file, it didn't need escaping. I just had to use the `r` for the `pattern`.

Comment: You are right, let me edit the answer, so others maybe could find answer easier.